# How to add data into postman

Tags: javascript, postman

If I want to add some data to my schema below:

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var notificationsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    notifyMessage                   : { 
            title                       : { type: String },
            des                         : { type: String }
        },
        notifier                        : { type: String },
        recipient                       : [{
            id                          : { type: String },
            status                      : {type:String,trim:true,enum:['read','unread']}
        }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('notification_tracker', notificationsSchema);
```

I tried this way:
[image]
[image]

But it ended up this way..

Comment: Please try sending as raw data in JSON format. Select radio button 'raw'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the **raw** radio button and make sure to set it as **JSON(application/json)** then paste or add your JSON object like this

[image]

```
{
  notifyMessage: {
    title: "",
    des: ""
  },
  notifier: "",
  recipient: [{
    id: "",
    status:""
  }, {
    id: "",
    status:""
  }]
}
```

Using this format

Comment: for recipient                       ?

Comment: same thing, you can add another object after notifyMessage.

Comment: @swatikiran I've updated my answer. You can use the format I've added and just update it depending on the value that you want

Comment: recipient is array... and at first im getting error saying' bad string' ... SyntaxError: Unexpected token n

Comment: @swatikiran oops. I've updated the answer. You can also look at http://json.org/example.html to see some sample format for JSON.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose "raw" option and not form-urlencoded, then just you put your json code:

```
    notifyMessage : { 
            title : something,
            des : something
        }}
...etc
```